# wmic csproduct get UUID equivalent for Unix and Mac?

Tags: macos, unix, uuid

is there an equivalent command for: "wmic csproduct get UUID" from Windows on Unix and Mac Systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dmidecode -s system-uuid
```

I believe this is the "Product ID", so it might be the same for all of the same products.  The man page for dmidecode lists other programs to get other information.

There is more information [at this link](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/System).